# Cause of induced EMF in a loop

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

Len'z law states that the change of magnetic field in a loop of wire produced current in a wire as the magnetic field in and out the loop.Although it just true experimentally, but

i) What happened with electron that they produced current when the magnetic field changed in the loop?

ii) Why the stationary magnetic field does not cause to flow of current in the wire.

iii) Which rule helps us to determined the direction of current either R.H rule or L.H rule.

Comment: I'm afraid that your statement of Lenz's law doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding (i), if the loop is stationary in your frame of reference, then electrons in the loop experience a force due to the 'tangential' electric field which surrounds the changing magnetic field.$$\textbf{F}=(-e) \textbf{E}$$ 
The existence of this electric field around a changing magnetic field, but not around a constant magnetic field, is a fundamental law of electromagnetism (a direct consequence of one of Maxwell's four equations).

As for (iii), neither right hand nor left hand rule is applicable if the loop is stationary in your frame of reference. Go back to Lenz's law: the direction of the induced emf is such that the effects of any current it drives oppose the change producing the emf. In this case the change I'd consider is the flux change.

If the change in magnetic field is due to the loop moving through a non-uniform field, or turning in a magnetic field, then the electrons in the wire are moving (because the wire they are in is moving!) in a magnetic field and experience 'motor effect' forces $$\textbf{F}=(-e) \textbf{v} \times \textbf{B}.$$ To find the direction of current you can either use Fleming's right hand rule or you can go back to first principles and apply Fleming's left hand rule to give the force direction on the electrons and hence the current direction (not forgetting that the electrons are negative).